# JavaFX, Flowpane with lots of buttons inside ScrollPane, slower wheel scroll with larger window

Tags: javafx

I have a FlowPane that gets programmatically filled with equal-sized buttons from a database table. This Flowpane is inside a Scrollpane and the application window is resizable. At the initial window size of 640x480 (set in scenebuilder), mouse-wheel scrolling speed is more or less acceptable, but if you resize the window larger, it gets progressively slower (up to unbearable when maximized).

I have fiddled around with the unit and block increments of the ScrollPane's Horizontal ScrollBar, but that doesn't seem to work very well and definitely does nothing for the mousewheel

I have been unable to find any information on how to change the mouse-wheel scroll amount (or of disabling the slow down if it is an intended effect), any help would be appreciated.